# Athena query results cleanup

Tags: amazon-web-services

Each time you run a query against Athena using the `aws` CLI tool, 2 files are created in the query results location.  Over time this location is going to contain a LOT of files unless they're cleaned up.

Is there a way to automatically clean them up?  If not, what's the best approach?  The `delete-named-query` CLI command only works if the query is named so it doesn't look like you can use that to clean up your results when you're finished with them.

Relevant part of the AWS documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use [S3 Lifecycle Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) for the Athena temp files cleanup.

Our `AthenaStagingDir` is `s3://.../tmp/` and we've got a **Lifecycle rule** for that `/tmp/` prefix that:

- expires *current objects* after 1 day and then
- deletes *previous objects* after another day (i.e. those expired the day before)

[image: Lifecycle policy]

I haven't found a way to immediately delete objects after 1 day but I haven't tried too hard to be honest. This 2-step / 2-day approach works well.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Just comment: "Athena work group" ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html ) says "Athena keeps a query history for 45 days.", but it just keeps history.  Output objects are still needed to be deleted by someway(e.g. lifecycle rule). thanks!